# Is there any tool to clean unused images in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I need a tool which will analyze unused images of Wordpress images folder.The tool which will check unattached images of website and display it so we can delete it.The tool can be free or paid. I don't want any kind of plugin.

Comment: Asking for tools, libraries, tutorials, or off-site resources recommendation is off-topic in here. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can recommend is that you do a good backup of your filesystem which would include the media library. *This step is not optional; it is required. You cannot trust any tools modifying or deleting your files.*

**Plugin:** [Media Cleaner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-cleaner/)

Media Cleaner cleans your Media Library from the media entries (and files) which aren’t used in your website, as well as broken entries. An internal trash allows you to make sure everything works properly before deleting the media entries (and files) permanently. It uses a smart analysis powered by many implementations for specific plugins and themes.

[image]

This is one of the most useful plugins I’ve come across.

Somehow a client managed to upload three copies of every single image she owned, each duplicate was a difference size, and all of them had to be checked. The unnecessary ones removed. This is the only tool I could find to fix the problems.

I’d recommend this plugin in a heartbeat.

Comment: their is no tool for the same

Comment: to analyze the files on server, code needs permission and embedding. Hence, this can not be done by any third part tool. You can achieve this only by using plugin which I have shared or by writing custom code in your site. Hope I made the point clear